# How to read function php and create a file xml

Tags: php

I need to read this function and create an xml with the title, description and etc fields.
then the table.

```
    public function defineCustomTemplate()
    {
        $this->setNmfile(302444);
        $this->setNmoperation("CPTEVALITHAB");
        $this->setNmimport(302433);

        $customTemplate = array();
        $customTemplate[] = array('column' => 'nmfield01', 'term' => 103571, 'dataType' => 2, 'precision' => 50, 'description' => 213795, 'required' => 1);
        $customTemplate[] = array('column' => 'nmfield02', 'term' => 102213, 'dataType' => 2, 'precision' => 50, 'description' => 302440, 'required' => 1);
        $customTemplate[] = array('column' => 'nmfield03', 'term' => 302442, 'dataType' => 2, 'precision' => 50, 'description' => 302442, 'required' => 1);
        $customTemplate[] = array('column' => 'nmfield04', 'term' => 302443, 'dataType' => 2, 'precision' => 50, 'description' => 302443, 'required' => 1);

        return $customTemplate;
    }
```

this function appears in several classes of the project and I would like to capture everywhere it is displayed and create the xml.

can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean, "read" the function? It _returns_ an array - so call it, and then work with the data - where is the problem with that?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SimpleXMLElement class in PHP to create an XML document with the data from the defineCustomTemplate() function.

Comment: You don't need to post an answer to guide people in their development. Just a comment is enough :)

Answer (score 1):

approximate solution without fields hardcoding

```
    $sxml = new  \SimpleXMLElement(('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><file></file>'));
    $sxml->addAttribute('filename', $Nmfile);

    $operation = $sxml->addChild('operations');
    $operation->addAttribute('opname', $Nmoperation);

    foreach ($customTemplate as $key => $item) {
        $serverKeys = array_keys($item);
        $import = $operation->addChild('import');
        $import->addAttribute('import_id', $Nmimport);

        foreach ($serverKeys as $i => $name) {
            $ops = $import->addChild($name);
            $ops->addAttribute($name,$item[$name]);
       }
    }

    var_dump($sxml->asXML());
```

output template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file filename="302444">
    <operations opname="CPTEVALITHAB">
        <import import_id="0">
            <column column="nmfield02"/>
            ...
        </import>

    </operations>
</file>
```